# Define an alternate exponential function?

Tags: real-analysis

Can you define another exponential function (lets call it $\text{Exp}_2$) so that $\text{Exp}_2 (r) = \text{Exp}(r)$ when $r$ is *rational*, and $\text{Exp}_2 (r) \ne \text{Exp}(r)$ when $r$ is *irrational*. And $\text{Exp}_2$ is continuous and differentiable everywhere.

Comment: No, because $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Hence continuity is enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that is impossible. Since the rationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, any two continuous functions that coincide on the rationals coincide on all of $\mathbb{R}$.